# Problems with custom macros in confluence

Tags: java, jira, confluence, jira-plugin

I have some problem with macros in confluence, 
i create TestMacro.java, TestTemplate.vm and add neccessary information in atllassian-plugin.xml such as

```
<macro name="test" class="path.TestMacro" key="test">
        <description>Test Macro</description>
</macro>
```

and then i add

```
{test}
```

to my confluence page, after refresh i see that macros not render, can anybody tell me a reason why it can be?

I have this error:

```
Unknown macro: {test}
```

Comment: Yeah, i find solution. I just forget to enable this macro in Confluense Admin -> Plugins page

Comment: So write an answer to your question and accept it, so that others see that the question is no more open ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why it not works before I just forget to enable this macro in Confluense Admin -> Plugins page